# Chrome window.postMessage to extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I developed a Chrome extension that get's a request from a webpage. For some reason, I do not see the request arriving at the extension. My web page request looks like that:

```
    $('#click').bind('click', function(e) {
        console.log('page javascript sending message');
        window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the web page!" }, "*");
    });
```

My extension like that:

```
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
    }, false);
```

And this is my manifest file:

{

```
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
```

}

Any idea why I do not see my request? It should be visible according to what I know.
Thanks!!

Comment: Never mind...I found out that the communication needs to go from the page --> Content Script --> background page. A direct communication to the background page does not seem to be possible. :)